# Account is no longer attached to the computer

Tags: user-accounts, user-profile, windows-registry

The comapny that I work for has split into different branches to become more efficient and I had to move from our main office into the smaller office. Now this place has a different domain and setup then the last office so I changed my domain information and restarted my computer. Upon the restart of my computer I had a blank desktop with non of my files or configurations. When I search my foolders I saw that all my files were there, and the account does show up in the registry under "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-3647962564-3202693172-2123812733-1166". Is there any way that I can re-enable this profile so that I may once again access it? I would really hate to redo all of my past configurations.

Comment: You should contact your IT help desk for this.

Comment: The problem is that our company is so small that they tied in programmers with the IT. So I am part of the 3 man IT team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue on my end. Apparently I had to change the registry settings to load in the profile that I wanted by changing the profile's load data. Now I have all my previous configurations loaded. All I have to do is to backup that folder so that the user account doesn't get mysteriously removed one day.

Answer (score 0):

If you have joined your machine to another domain then it will have created you a new profile. If you look in your users directory you will likely see a folder labelled username.domain, this will be your new profile. You can locate your old profile in the users folder and copy the areas you want to move into your new one.

However, if you want to move more than just your desktop settings my docs etc, then you may need to get someone from IT to do this for you. It may be wise to do that anyway.